# Create a link to download an image currently displayed on a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, download

I'm developing an offline HTML box that is displayed into a Windows Application.

The app (created in Autoplay Media Studio) shows an iexplore box to load the html. I've scripted an Iexplore 11 silent install before the app first load.

I'm using Jquery Fullsizable (https://github.com/MSchmidt/jquery-fullsizable) to display the images in "fullscreen" (Fullscreen inside the box).

As Fullsizable is a lightbox, where you can change the image with next and previous buttons, the image src path changes. That's the reason I need a code to extract the current img src file path when you click on the link/button and download it, asking the place on the disk where the image will be saved.

This is the container structure image

```
<div id="fullsized_image_holder" style="display: table-cell;"><img src="foto11.jpg" style="margin-top: 0px;"></div>
```

What's the best way to create a link to download an image currently displayed on a div?

I think there may be a simple way to get it with JS, something like `<a href=the SRC of the <img> that's inside the #fullsized_image_holder DIV download="actualfilename">`

All this on a offline environment.

Comment: thanks a lot to correct my poor english!

Answer (score 0):

Well, thanks a lot for Vladislav Zorov from Quora to approach a lot to the solution.

```
<a href="#" onclick="this.href = $('#fullsized_image_holder img:first').attr('src');"
download>Click here to download image</a>
```

This is the solution using Jquery (and im actually using Jquery)

Now, as is for Iexplorer only, i have to force the browser prompt the user the place to image will be saved.

There's a solution:

`document.execCommand('SaveAs','true','http://www.google.com')`, but i need to insert `this.href = $('#fullsized_image_holder img:first').attr('src');` in the place of 'http://www.google.com'